# If button pressed X times within 1 second, do this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm wondering how to make it if, for example, button "F" being pressed 5 times within a second, do // something.

How though? At first, I thought about doing something like this:

```
private float totalCount = 0f;
private float countOne = 1f;

void Update(){

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F)){

        totalCount += countOne;
    }

    if (totalCount == 5){

        // do some thing
    }
}
```

But obviously, this isn't exactly what I want. So how do I achieve that? Coroutine?

Comment: Record the time of first time pressing and increment value untill the time difference between frist press and current time is less or equal to 5, else change the count to 1 again.

Comment: Record a list of actoins with a time stamp

Comment: Maintain a queue of timestamps, add the current timestamp to the end, remove timestamps that are older than 1 second from the start, if the queue at any point contains 5 or more items, you got your situation. You would then probably clear the queue and "do some thing"

Answer (score 3):

Rx is an ideal way of doing this. You can use a simple buffer of one second.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace Anything
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] _)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Keys()
                .ToObservable()
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Value = x,
                    Seconds = sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
                })
                .Buffer(5, 1)
                .Where(xs => xs.Last().Seconds - xs.First().Seconds <= 1.0)
                .Subscribe(ks => Console.WriteLine($"More than five! {ks.Count}"));
        }

        public static IEnumerable<ConsoleKeyInfo> Keys()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                yield return Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If many calls (much more than 5) are made every second the buffer will work very hard! You should limit it size as well

Comment: Your query doesn't work. Try it with this source: `var rnd = new Random(); Observable.Generate(0, x => true, x => x + 1, x => x, x => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(rnd.NextDouble() / 5.0))`

Comment: It doesn't get overlapping groups of clicks.

Comment: @Enigmativity you have way more Rx experience than me. Part of my learning has been from reading your past SO answers, so if you want to give the OP the 'right' way to do it, go ahead.

Comment: @Aaron - Thanks for the recognition. I'm happy for you to post the answer. Try `.Select(x => new { value = x, seconds = sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds }).Buffer(5, 1).Where(xs => xs.Last().seconds - xs.First().seconds <= 1.0)`, where `sw` is a running `Stopwatch` instance, instead of your `Buffer`/`Where` combo.

Comment: Does Rx work in Unity environment? I couldn't get it to work in plain Unity but there seems to be Unity specific (re)implementations in GitHub that I haven't tested.

Comment: @Mikko Koivisto I don't know, I've never used Unity. I wrote the above example in a normal console app. Edit: Just did a quick Google search and it looks like Rx isn't supported for Unity, however it also appears that someone has created a library that does: https://github.com/neuecc/UniRx

Comment: @MikkoKoivisto - Yes, Rx should work fine in Unity. You need your namespaces at the top.

Answer (score 2):

If performance is not a problem, you could try this (haven't tested it):

```
private float totalCount = 0f;
private float countOne = 1f;
private List<DateTime> pressedTime = new List<DateTime>();

void Update(){

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F)){

        pressedTime.Add(DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")));
    }

    if (pressedTime.Count == 5){
        if ( (DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")) - pressedTime[0]).Seconds <= 1)
            do stuff
        pressedTime.Remove(0);
    }
}
```

**EDIT :** With queues

```
private float totalCount = 0f;
private float countOne = 1f;
private Queue<DateTime> myQ = new Queue<DateTime>();

void Update(){

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F)){

        pressedTime.Enqueue(DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")));
    }

    if (pressedTime.Count == 5){
        if ( (DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")) - pressedTime.Peek()).Seconds <= 1)
            do stuff
        pressedTime.Dequeue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider a queue for this types of actions

Comment: Oh yes, indeed, I'm not used to work with queue. Is it better for performance ?

Comment: Well, for me it's more clear. The time complexity is the same

Comment: `DateTime.Now` doesn't have the resolution to accurately track this time - it'll round the seconds and allow more that 1 second of clicks to be grouped together. You need a `Stopwatch` instance to track the time properly.

Comment: If the default precision is not good enough, what about a simple fix, such as :   DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString('"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")) ? There is no need to create a new instance in my honest opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get System.Reactive answer work in Unity and Unity has Time.realtimeSinceStartup that could be used instead of DateTime so I wrote one more example:

```
public float interval = 1f;
public int count = 5;
private Queue<float> timeStamps = new Queue<float>();

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F)) {
        float secsNow = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        timeStamps.Enqueue(secsNow);
        if (timeStamps.Count >= count) {
            float oldest = timeStamps.Dequeue();
            if (secsNow - oldest < interval) {
                Debug.Log("pressed " + count + " times in " + (secsNow - oldest) + "sec");
            }
        }
    }

}
```